# How send array in fileTransfer option object in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ngcordova

I want to save the image using fileTransfer in Ionic 2.

How to send `array` in `fileTransfer` object. I didn't get it on the server side.

```
   var options = {
      fileKey: "file",
      fileName: filename,
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "image/jpg",
      headers : {},
      params: {
        'file': filename,
        'rId': this.rId,
        'model':{ 'RId': this.rId }
      }
    };

    const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }, err => {
      console.log("Upload Err : "+ err);
    });
  }
```

Here at server side `rId` and file values are getting but model is not displaying any value.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the object to JSON and then sending it in the model parameter and then on the server side, use JSON decode method to get the original object.

e.g.

```
var modelObj = JSON.stringify({ 'RId': this.rId });

var options = {
  fileKey: "file",
  fileName: filename,
  chunkedMode: false,
  mimeType: "image/jpg",
  headers : {},
  params: {
    'file': filename,
    'rId': this.rId,
    'model': modelObj
  }
};
```